# Set radius for each corner with rounded rect?

Tags: c#

Here's the source code which makes form corner rounded,

but how could I set own radius with each corner?

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
            int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
         );

        public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 405, 546, 20, 20));
```

I want only top-left corner rounded.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it yourself.

Use a `GraphicsPath`, and then convert it to a `Region` using the [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfywt1c(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a `GraphicsPath`

```
using (GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath())
{
    int d = CornerRadius * 2;
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top, d, d, 180, 90);
    gfxPath.AddLine(Bounds.Right, Bounds.Top, Bounds.Right, Bounds.Bottom);
    gfxPath.AddLine(Bounds.Right, Bounds.Bottom, Bounds.Left, Bounds.Bottom);
    gfxPath.CloseAllFigures();
    region = new Region(gfxPath);
}
```